# I'm creating a JSON column from a table but I want the to be ordered by date, how can I go about it?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say I have a table like this

| Product_ID | TRX_DT | TRX_AMT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB-001 | 2022-10-01 | 576.06 |
| AB-001 | 2022-02-02 | 864.56 |
| AB-001 | 2020-08-27 | 698.20 |
| AB-001 | 2006-09-01 | 468.36 |
| AB-008 | 2017-10-14 | 357.58 |
| AB-008 | 2020-11-17 | 950.14 |
| AB-008 | 2012-05-07 | 120.06 |
| AB-008 | 2008-01-01 | 267.52 |

So I want to create a json file that groups all transactions per product like this:

```
SELECT 
    TO_JSON(
        OBJECT_CONSTRUCT_KEEP_NULL(
            'Product_ID', ANY_VALUE(t.Product_ID),
            'Transactions', ARRAY_AGG(
                    OBJECT_CONSTRUCT_KEEP_NULL(
                      'TRANSACTION_DATE', t.TRX_DT,
                      'TRANSACTION_AMOUNT', t.TRX_AMT
                    )
                     ))
            ) AS json,
    CONCAT(
        'Company_', 
        '_', t.Product_ID 
            ) AS product_code
FROM product_history AS t
GROUP BY t.Product_ID
```

With this I'm getting all products with the transactions into one JSON column, but the problem is that the transactions inside the 'Transactions' new field are not in order and I need them in ascendant order. How could I go about it?

I tried a simple `ORDER BY t.Product_ID, t.TRX_DT` at the end but of course it didn't didn't allow it.

Answer (score 1):

on the ARRAY_AGG add the clause `within group (order by t.trx_amt)`

```
with cte(Product_ID, TRX_DT, TRX_AMT) as (
    select * from values    
    ('AB-001','2022-10-01'::date,   576.06),
    ('AB-001','2022-02-02'::date,   864.56),
    ('AB-001','2020-08-27'::date,   698.20),
    ('AB-001','2006-09-01'::date,   468.36),
    ('AB-008','2017-10-14'::date,   357.58),
    ('AB-008','2020-11-17'::date,   950.14),
    ('AB-008','2012-05-07'::date,   120.06),
    ('AB-008','2008-01-01'::date,   267.52)
)
select OBJECT_CONSTRUCT_KEEP_NULL(
            'Product_ID', ANY_VALUE(t.Product_ID),
            'Transactions', ARRAY_AGG(
                    OBJECT_CONSTRUCT_KEEP_NULL(
                      'TRANSACTION_DATE', t.TRX_DT,
                      'TRANSACTION_AMOUNT', t.TRX_AMT
                    )
                 ) within group (order by t.TRX_DT)
            )
from cte as t
group by t.product_id;
```

gives:

| OBJECT_CONSTRUCT_KEEP_NULL( 'PRODUCT_ID', ANY_VALUE(T.PRODUCT_ID), 'TRANSACTIONS', ARRAY_AGG( OBJECT_CONSTRUCT_KEEP_NULL( 'TRANSACTION_DATE', T.TRX_DT, 'TRANSACTION_AM |
| --- |
| { "Product_ID": "AB-001", "Transactions": [ { "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": 468.36, "TRANSACTION_DATE": "2006-09-01" }, { "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": 698.2, "TRANSACTION_DATE": "2020-08-27" }, { "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": 864.56, "TRANSACTION_DATE": "2022-02-02" }, { "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": 576.06, "TRANSACTION_DATE": "2022-10-01" } ] } |
| { "Product_ID": "AB-008", "Transactions": [ { "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": 267.52, "TRANSACTION_DATE": "2008-01-01" }, { "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": 120.06, "TRANSACTION_DATE": "2012-05-07" }, { "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": 357.58, "TRANSACTION_DATE": "2017-10-14" }, { "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT": 950.14, "TRANSACTION_DATE": "2020-11-17" } ] } |